# Matlab "Assertion Failed" error as parfor goind on?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, runtime-error, parfor

I have the code segment

```
display('Descriptor Extraction...');

DESCRIPTORS = {};
descriptor_for_each_class = {};
num_classes = length(imgs_dir);
IMAGES = {};
for i = 1:num_classes
    class_name = classes{i};
    fprintf('Feature Extraction for CLASS %s\n',class_name);
    full_path = fullfile(imgs_path,class_name);

    class_dir = dir(full_path);
    image_names = {class_dir(3:length(class_dir)).name};
    num_imgs = length(image_names);

    descriptors = {};
    parfor j = 1:num_imgs
        image_name = image_names{j};
        %fprintf('Feature Extraction for IMAGE %d/%d\n',j,num_imgs);
        img_path = fullfile(full_path,image_name);
        I = imread(img_path(:,:));
        I = standarizeImage(I);
        I = rgb2gray(I) ;
        IMAGES{i,j}.I = I;
        IMAGES{i,j}.class_name = class_name;
        IMAGES{i,j}.name = image_name;
        [f, d] = vl_dsift(I, 'size', binSize) ;
        descriptors{j}=d;
    end
    DESCRIPTORS = [DESCRIPTORS descriptors];
end
```

and when the parfor section completed one epoch, at the very beginning of the second epoch Matlab gives following error:

```
Error using parallel_function (line 589)
Assertion failed.

Error in feat_extraction (line 34)
    parfor j = 1:num_imgs
```

I could not find the bug on the code. Is there any idea?

Comment: Can you minimize the code in both loops and still be able to reproduce the error?

Answer (score 2):

I solve the problem by changing the parfor section as below

```
descriptors = {};
    images = {};
    parfor j = 1:num_imgs
        image_name = image_names{j};
        %fprintf('Feature Extraction for IMAGE %d/%d\n',j,num_imgs);
        img_path = fullfile(full_path,image_name);
        I = imread(img_path(:,:));
        images{j}.I = I;
        images{j}.class_name = class_name;
        images{j}.image_name = image_name;
        I = standarizeImage(I);
        I = rgb2gray(I) ;
        %IMAGES{i,j}.name = image_name;
        [f, d] = vl_dsift(I, 'size', binSize) ;
        descriptors{j}=d;
    end
    ALL_DATA{i}=images;
    DESCRIPTORS = [DESCRIPTORS descriptors];
end
```

Comment: What was the reason for the problem?

Comment: I was using the index, comming from outer for loop's i so when the i value is changed other matlab instances having problem for indexing of IMAGES inside parfoor.

Comment: I got this error in a parfor because I forgot to preinitialise one of my output arrays, so if one worker finished iteration n+1 before another finished iteration n it couldn't dynamically resize the array properly. Preinit fixed it of course, and this answer gave me the hint - completely different problem space but similar structure.

Comment: xenoclast's explanation fixed my problem.

Comment: Anyone else find this a very poor error message for Matlab to throw in this situation? Surely it should be improved?